# Append JPG to MPG Video ffmpeg/mencoder

Tags: video, jpeg, mencoder

I've found a lot of solutions for creating a video from a folder of jpgs, in this case a time lapse stream of photos from a camera.  Thats easy, but seems to waste a lot of computing power regenerating the whole mpg ever 30 seconds/minute/etc.

Is there a way to append jpgs to an exist mpg while keeping the same framerate and any other parameters?

My current video file is created using:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 1 -vcodec mjpeg -i -r 30 - out.mpg
```

Thanks